# Make refresh page function run only once per session

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I need to run a function ONLY ONCE if the value in the cart is lower than X amount, then refresh the page. Right now i have it almost working, except that it keeps executing constantly, I cant make it scape from the loop even if it has already executed once, it keeps refreshing the site:

```
/* Avoid 0 value order checkout */
add_action( 'woocommerce_check_cart_items', 'wc_minimum_order_amount' );
function wc_minimum_order_amount() {
    // Set this variable to specify a minimum order value
    static $foo_called = false;
    if ($foo_called) return;
    $minimum = 100;
    if ( WC()->cart->total < $minimum ) {         
         header("Refresh:0");
         $foo_called = true;
    } else $foo_called = true;
}
```

Thanks
Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

Try to save the flag in a session variable and add the session value to the condition

```
function wc_minimum_order_amount() {
    // Set this variable to specify a minimum order value
    $_SESSION["flag"]= false;
   
    $minimum = 100;
    if ((WC()->cart->total < $minimum) && !$_SESSION["flag"]) {         
         header("Refresh:0");
         $_SESSION["flag"] = true;
    } else if(WC()->cart->total >= $minimum){ 
         $_SESSION["flag"] = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: First of all, thanks for your help, and thanks for showing me the session thing, that is pretty clever. Because of the nature of the purpose i want this to work, my only way to test if it is working (or i can think of) is to change the $_SESSION["flag"] = true; to false, so i can see it looping constantly, and it seems is not refreshing the site, i dont know if you understand what i mean.

Comment: So, basically i have commented the line $_SESSION["flag"] = true; inside the if statement (so it should infinite loop), but it is not looping, so unless I did not understood your aproach, it seems to not be working.

Comment: To test that it works correctly you should only add in your shopping cart an amount less than the specified one, if you read the code once the page reload condition is met, you will not enter that condition again until the opposite happens (exceed or equal the minimum purchase value) or the variable is reset to its original value when completing the order (this must be done or the session will keep the last value)

Comment: I did, and it does not refresh... correct me if im wrong, but.. might it be you are using the wrong $_SESSION["flag"] instead of $_SESSION['flag']... just asking

Comment: Im trying to understand your code using what is shown in here https://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1048666

Comment: The flag what it indicates is when the condition has already been met, if you want to test the code you must verify the value of the flag, the code says that if the flag is true deny the condition and do not let it enter (! $ _ SESSION [" flag "]), so it is important that you set a flag reset location and for testing ensure that the flag is at an initial value of false

Comment: I have used your code above, and it is not refreshing when condition is not met... and i cant figure out why.. i wish i can send you details of the site so you can see it is not working.... aaaaaaaaaaarggggg, once again i really appreciate your help.

Comment: Sessions are variables that last over time, if the first condition has already been met, the value of the session must be true and the site will not be refreshed, try using var_dump ($ _ SESSION ["flag"]) to verify the value of the session, if the value is true it is because it already did a page reload, thanks to that the initial request is fulfilled (run only once per session), I cannot review the site you are working on, I hope I was from it helps but I can't do much more

Comment: Im using private browsing when doing the test, isnt that as good as dumping the variable?